# SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED error shown when Chromedriver turned 1800-1900 pages using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, windows-10, selenium-chromedriver

```
driver_t = webdriver.Chrome()
driver_t.implicitly_wait(5)
driver_t.get(Company intranet)

elem = driver_t.find_element_by_id("j_username")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(".....")
elem = driver_t.find_element_by_id("j_password")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(".....")
driver_t.find_element_by_id("frm-ok").click()
driver_t.maximize_window()


page_counter = 0  ***#10 items in 1 page, WHEN TURN PAGE ABOUT 189, ERROR HAPPEN***
while True:
    els = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='flexme1']/tbody/tr")
    cnt = len(els)
    if not cnt:
        print(time.asctime(), "This page has no orders.")
        break

    page_counter = page_counter + 1
    print(time.asctime(), "Page Counter: ", page_counter)

    oi_l = craw.fetch_order_info(driver)

    for i in range(1, cnt + 1):
        last_id, od_l = craw.fetch_order_detail(driver, last_id, i)

    page_down = "//form[@name='frmList']/div[5]/div[2]/ul/li[9]/a"
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(page_down)
    class_name = elem.get_attribute('class')
    if "disable" in class_name:
        print(time.asctime(), "Task finished.")
        break

    elem.click()
```

## When the outter loop run about 150-200 times, chrome crashed.

How resolve this problem?
Somewhere said that chrome maintain a deep history list, is the answer?

Comment: What is the system configuration on which you are running this? Have you been able to manually go beyond 200 pages in your browser?

Answer (score 3):

This error...

[image: SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED]

...implies that there is a huge memory consumption issue in Chrome that cause tabs to crash with SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED error.

---

### Deep Dive

As per the article [SBOX FATAL MEMORY EXCEEDED constantly and chrome is using large amounts of memory](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/33546011?hl=en) this issue of Chrome consuming huge memory is observed with all of the following instances:

- Google Chrome version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Google Chrome version 82.0.4083.0 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Google Chrome version 82.0.4085.4 canary (64-bit)

mostly with in [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) systems when **ESET NOD32 Antivirus 13.0.24.0** is installed.

---

Snapshot of Chrome high memory consumption:

[image: ESET]

Snapshot of high memory usage by Chrome:

[image: ESET1]

As per the article [Eset consumes major memory w/ Chrome](https://forum.eset.com/topic/22924-eset-consumes-major-memory-w-chrome/) with in ESET Security Forum:

> Major issue with Eset NOD AV 13.0.24.0 and 13.1.16.0 and Chrome: Since Chrome update to 82.0.4083 (and later 82.0.4085.4 being the latest) both on Canary and Dev channels, there's a HUGE memory consumption issue in Chrome (>8GB) on (almost) all sites (especially gmail) that cause tabs to crash with SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED error. Removing NOD resolves the issue, reinstalling it back recreates it and so forth. There's no such issue in Chrome Canary and Dev 82.0.4077.0.

---

### Solution

As per the ESET support article [KB3415](https://support.eset.com/en/kb3415-enable-pre-release-updates-in-eset-windows-home-products) he most effective solution would be to enable pre-release updates in ESET Windows home products. Steps:

- Enable pre-release updates to resolve an issue with your product.
- Switch back to a regular update.

---

### tl; dr

We have discussed this issue at length within the discussion [ESET causing excessive renderer memory usage](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1060652) and the issue had been removed from the queue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your answer and edit my question. Problem resolved.

Comment: Bad news, it happen again. Yesterday update Win10 and run more than 20 hours, nothing happen. Today I change nothing but happen twice, one at 178 page, other at 196 page. I downloaded Nod AV remover to clean my os, found nothing. (More than a month ago, have installed NOD, and remove it few days later.)  chrome version:81.0.4044.138 64bit, Win10.

Comment: This error happened to me in Azure Portal. A lot of stuff going on in the background on that site.